# How to download files to Google Drive directly using Dolphin?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, kde, google-drive, dolphin-file-manager

I recently installed Fedora 38 (KDE) and add my google account. I also installed `kio-gdrive`. Now I can see a `Google Drive` folder under `Network` folder. And there is another folder named `google1` for my account under `Google Drive` folder. I renamed it. Now whenever I try to download something to my `google1` folder, save button stops working and download dialog gets closed and nothing gets downloaded. I tried in edge and chrome, both didn't work. I tried firefox which doesn't even have the `Network` in Download Dialog. So, how can I download a file to Google Drive directly?

Comment: You can't unless you have a sync client for Google Drive, not the thing you installed, which is similar to the Gnome integration. Both let you download from / copy somewhere else (*downloading* from GDrive). Neither allows saving a file to the their "virtual" folders and expect it to sync up to GDrive. There are no official sync for Linux, there are unnoficial and paid alternative software.